# if $f : X \to Y$ is continuous for every topology, then $f$ is constant

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Prove that a function $f : X \to Y$ is continuous for every topology
on $X$ and every topology on $Y$ if and only if f is constant, that is, $f(x) = f(y)$ for all
$x, y \in X$.

I managed to prove the converse, which is quite easy. However couldn't prove the way : $\implies$

My approach in proving the way $\implies$ was letting a topology on $X$ to be discrete while letting the topology on $Y$ to be indiscrete. And using contradiction. But this didn't work out, I need to somehow show that for every topology $f$ should be constant but couldn't think of such a general argument.

I also thought about using the fact that inverse functions preserves unions and intersection, so that for any $ \alpha_i \in Top(Y)$ Inverse of their unions should be in $Top(X)$ was my argument, which I believe could lead to the solution.

Any hints?

Comment: You only need to show that $f$ is constant for one topology, because topology can't affect whether $f$ is constant :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go the other way! Let $Y$ have discrete topology and $X$ have the trivial one. Then note that for any $y\in Y$, $\{y\}$ is an open set, so $f^{-1}(y)\subseteq X$ must also be open.

The moral of the story is that it is more difficult for a function $X\to Y$ to be continuous with a coarse topology on $X$ and a fine topology on $Y$ is. Simply because there are more open $V\subseteq Y$ that puts demands on $f$, and there are fewer open $U\subseteq X$ you are allowed to "hit" with $f^{-1}(V)$. This goes the other way too; if $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is trivial, then *any* function $X\to Y$ is continuous.

Comment: And so, $f^{-1}(y)$ must be all of $X$, or empty.

Comment: @B.Mehta Exactly.

Comment: @Arthurt I have a problem with the terminology you use here. You say that $f^{-1}(y) \subset X$ must also be open. However, I think $f^{-1}(y) \subset X$ is either all of $X$ or empty. $X$ could be closed too, why are we assuming $X$ is open?

I have this problem about continuity of a function $f$ vs continuity of a function $f$ with respects to topologies on domain and the range. I somewhat learned that, we don't need to requirement for inverse image of an open set to be open if we restrict $f$ to a topology as we do here.

Comment: @Arthur and why is a point $y \in Y$ open?

Comment: @Xenidia This is by [definition of discrete topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space)

Comment: @Xenidia There is nothing stopping a set from being both open and closed at the same time (so-called _clopen_). In fact, by the definition of a topology and closed set, the whole set and the empty set are necessarily clopen. $\{y\}$ is open because that's what the discrete topology is: all sets are open (and therefore also closed). $f^{-1}(y)$ must therefore be open by definition of continuous. The only options, by definition of trivial topology, is $\varnothing$ or $X$. Exactly one of them must be $X$, and the rest $\varnothing$ by definition of function.

Comment: @Arthurt Thanks, You've made everything much more clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x,x'\in X$ with $x\ne x'$ and $f(x)\ne f(x^*).$ Let $T_X=\{\phi,X, \{x\}\}.$ Let $T_Y=\{\phi,Y, \{f(x^*)\}\}.$

Then $\{f(x^*)\}\in T_Y$ but $f^{-1}\{f(x^*)\} \not \in T_X$ so $f$ is not continuous.

So if $f:X\to Y$ is not constant then there exist topologies on $X,Y$ such that f is not continuous.

The smallest example of this is $X=Y=\{1,2\}$ and $T_X=T_Y=\{\phi, \{1\},X\}$ (Sierpinski space) with $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=1.$